# Only Kohanim get reward for mitzvos in this world

Tags: sources-mekorot, mitzvah, kohen-priest, reward-punishment

There's a concept of שכר מצוות בהאי עלמא ליכא, there is no reward for *mitzvos* in this world ([Kiddushin 39b](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.39b.6&lang=bi)). Much has been written on what this means and why it's true, but I found a innovative idea that the Chasam Sofer writes ([Toras Moshe to Bamidbar 25:11 § פנחס](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21621&pgnum=105)) that this is only true for Leviim and Yisraelim. Kohanim do receive reward for *mitzvos* in this world (see there for the reason).

This is such a innovative idea I was wondering if anyone else says such a thing?

Comment: Adding his reasoning in English could cast a wider net of.potential answers

Comment: @JoshK I'm asking regardless of his reasoning. maybe someone else agrees that kohanim are rewarded but for a different reason.